Exercise 4, Section 5.3 of Hungerford’s Algebra
Hungerford, Algebra, page 257, gives the following as Definition 3.1:
Let $S$ be a set of polynomials of positive degree in $K[x]$. an extension field $F$ of $K$ is said to be a splitting field over $K$ of the set $S$ of polynomials if every polynomial in $S$ splits in $F[x]$ and $F$ is generated over $K$ by the roots of all the polynomials in $S$.
A note preceding the exercises at the end of Section 5.3 says,
Unless stated otherwise $F$ is always an extension field of the field $K$ and $S$ is a set of polynomials (of positive degree) in $K[x]$.

If $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of $S$, then $F$ is also a splitting field over $K$ of the set $T$ of all irreducible factors of polynomials in $S$.

Asking for clarification: “irreducible factors” means irreducible factors in $K[x]$ or $F[x]$?
Why this exercise is really needed? I mean it is essentially special case of “if” part of exercise 1 section 5.3.
Exercise 1: $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of a finite set $\{f_1,\dotsc,f_n\}$ of polynomials in $K[x]$ if and only if $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of the single polynomial $f=f_1f_2\dotsb f_n$.

Logically it should be in $K[x], $ since $F$ is created from $K$ and the problem asks to show the two ways to create $F$ yield the same results.

You can not use exercise 1, section 5.3 since $S$ is possibly infinite.

I meant in following sense: $\forall f=f_1\cdots f_n\in S$ where $f_i$’s are irreducible factors of $f$ in $K[x]$, we have each $f_i$ split in $F[x]$ and roots of $f$ in $F$ is equal to roots of $f_i$’s in $F$. Thus $F$ is splitting field of $T$ over $K$.
